# Is this homomorphism one-to-one?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

The question is: Let $\phi$:($Z_4'$) -> ($Z_8'$) be a homomorphism such that $\phi(1)$ = 6. Find $\phi(3)$ and is $\phi$ one-to-one?

Can someone please explain to me how one would go about solving this?

Thank you!

Comment: What does $Z_n'$ mean in this context?

Comment: Can't be one to one because assuming $Z_4$ has 4 elements and $Z_8$ 8 elements. Also think there are two groups of order 4 up to isomorphism, one cyclic, the other $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: K it is one to one can't be unto*

Comment: @marshalcraft: You mean onto, not unto. Anyway, I wonder who had the idea that “one-to-one” would be a good English term for “injective”; for (apparently not only) me the natural meaning of “one-to-one” would be “bijective”.

Comment: @celtschk I suppose they thought that 'bijective' meant that would the 'bi' would denote two properties of the function or operator. English is strange however, no doubt there.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "$Z_n'$" means $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

We have $\phi(3) = \phi(1+1+1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1) + \phi(1) = 6 + 6 + 6 \equiv 2 \operatorname{Mod} 8$.

Likewise, $\phi(2) = 12 \equiv 4 \operatorname{Mod} 8$ and of course $\phi(0) = 0$.

Hence, $\phi$ is injective since $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},\, x\neq y \Rightarrow \phi(x) \neq \phi(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(3)=2$.

It's one-one because $\operatorname {ker}\phi=0$.

For $\phi(1)=6,\phi(2)=4,\phi(3)=2$.

Comment: How did you compute the kernel of $\phi$?

Comment: I checked the image of each of $0,1,2$ and $3$.  Only $0$ went to $0$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you find the value of $\phi (3)$? The solution gives $phi(3)$ = $\phi(3) = \phi(3 . 1) = \phi(1) = 3 . 6 = 2$. Though I'm not sure I understand how they came to this.

Comment: Yes.  $3=3\cdot 1$.  So $\phi(3)=3\cdot\phi(1)=2$.  Remember $18\cong2\pmod8$.

Comment: It's the property of homomorphisms:   $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster This clears it up tons! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure @RahulFernandez.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes I did not recall that the mod operator was involved here.